# How does one write a scala unit test for the "filter" function?

Tags: scala, unit-testing

I'm taking Odersky's Coursera Scala course and I am struggling with writing a unit test for the "filter" function in Lesson 2 (return a subset of set s for which p holds).  We made a Type alias Set = Int => Boolean.  I managed to write the function in a satisfyingly functional way that I can clearly see is working correctly.  I claim this because I can use the supplied printSet function for a large variety of applied pre-defined sets and predicates and see that the expected result appears in the console.  I understand that our Type alias is saying that we are really just defining a rule that determines the members of the set, not the set itself.

The real problem I am having is that I am not skilled at writing unit tests, and I cannot imagine how to make an assert that tests my filter(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean) function.

Part of the problem, I think, is one of not knowing how to compare two sets.  Trying to literally assert that the subset returned from "filter" equals a defined result, I tried things like this:

```
val sampleSet = List(-1, 0, 1).toSet
val odd: Set = x => x % 2 != 0
val sampleResult = List(-1, 1).toSet
assert( filter(sampleSet, odd).equals(sampleResult) )  //nope, doesn't work.  Returns false.
assert( filter(sampleSet, odd) == sampleResult )       //no good either
```

How does one simply compare whether two sets contain the exact same values?  Am I being too literal?  I'm certainly feeling uncommonly stupid.

Can anyone suggest to me a way to write a unit test for this?  The unit tests are not graded, and I already have my function working fine, so it seems to me within the bounds of the Coursera honor code to ask.  Even a hint to get my head straight would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you call `List.toSet` you get back a *scala* `Set` (`scala.collection.immutable.Set`), not *your* `Set`:

```
scala> val sampleResult = List(-1, 1).toSet
sampleResult: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(-1, 1)
```

Since you've defined `filter` to return an object of your `Set` type, not `scala.collection.immutable.Set`, they will never be equal.

Writing a correct test for your method is a little tricky because your `Set` is a function that can take any `Int` as input.  Since it's not practical to assert on every possible `Int` value, you might be best off just asserting some relevant inputs:

```
assert(false, filter(sampleSet, odd)(-2))
assert(true,  filter(sampleSet, odd)(-1))
assert(false, filter(sampleSet, odd)(0))
...
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much.  I had to write them as assert(filter(sampleSet, odd)(-2)), but that is exactly what I needed to see.  Had I simply done these in a scala worksheet or sbt I would have seen the compiler statements and realized this.  Cheers from Indiana, USA.